# Disconnect breaker upgrade 125A -> 200A

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

I am looking to upgrade my 125A service to 200A but the electrician is having a tough time finding a 200A breaker. My condo was built in 1987 and the company, Crouse Hinds that makes the breaker is no longer in business.  I know there are companies that support the same breaker type but have not been able to find the breaker.

The meter stack contained 3 meters and 3 disconnects. At first I thought maybe the electrician can bypass the disconnect and go directly to the panel since the new panel will have a main breaker to shut off the power to the house, but I heard disconnects are now required according to NEC 2020 so bypassing probably will not fly with an inspector plus it helps to total cut power to the panel.

Is my only option to put in a new meter enclosure off from the current stack and if so is that even allowed. I mean can a metal plate be put over the old meter opening to cover it and remove the old breaker and cover that opening with a metal cover secured with screws?

Of course my best option is to find a 200A disconnect breaker.

Here is the text on the label of the breaker:

LISTED CKT 8RKR

8 POLE UNIT ISSUE LM-5914
TYPE MP-A

INTERRUPTING RATING:

10,000 AMP RMS SYM

120/240 VAC CU/AL

TORQUE: 90 LB-IN

MOUNT ON VERTICAL

SURFACE ONLY

CROUSE-HINDS E13207

Service Line Panel and Meter Stack - https://imgur.com/26qkZ5d

Meter Stack with Disconnect Panel Removed - https://imgur.com/QClD8D4

125A Disconnect Breaker Label - https://imgur.com/uE72Oe3

Meter & Disconnect - https://imgur.com/Hn6xfit

3 Meters & Disconnects - https://imgur.com/33sdSxX

Crouse Hinds 125A Disconnect Breaker Closeup - https://imgur.com/v7iJeMI

Service Lines next to Meter Stack - https://imgur.com/Q6TrwsX

Comment: Post the photos to [imgur](https://imgur.com) and post a link here, we can help you get them attached

Comment: Don't reduce picture resolution. Do a "Save as..." and pick "JPEG" and then reduce the "Q"uality slider (1-12) to 3.  Vastly smaller file size, and we can still see detail.

Comment: Can you get us photos of the label on the inside bottom left of the customer compartment you opened up please? (Also, I sincerely hope you didn't break any utility seals in the process of getting those photos)

Comment: Meter Stack Side Label - https://imgur.com/BSZ3owJ

Meter Stack Top Label - https://imgur.com/KtUeUKb

Terminal Box Label - https://imgur.com/abC94hI

Comment: @LukeCatania -- who do you have for an electric utility btw?

Comment: Dominion Energy is the service provider.

Answer (score 2):

### There is no way to get a 200A main out of that box

Unfortunately, what you have there is an obsolete/discontinued piece of modular metering hardware that only supports 125A per meter, as both the sockets themselves and the disconnect positions are rated for 125A maximum.

You'd need to tap the main horizontal bus or the service wires somehow, or alternately somehow find a 200A module for that particular modular metering line gathering dust on a shelf somewhere, in order to have a 200A service.  Of course, if the rest of your condo neighbors agree, it'd be possible to do a wholesale upgrade to get everyone the option of a 200A service, but that'd require replacing the entire modular metering assembly with a currently supported product.

Comment: If that is so, how can Dominion Energy place a 200A Meter into the meter socket.  Wouldn't that mean that 200 amps is coming into the meter stack & it's just 125A breaker that is reducing the service.  Does it break NEC if Dominion put in a 200A meter?

Since the 200A panel I want to have installed has a disconnect on the panel, would there be any way to bypass the disconnect on the meter stack.  I don't know NEC, so I am just throwing things out.  Rather than using a breaker at the disconnect is there any way to wire to the meter stack bus using slip-on/fast-on or a bolt-on connectors.

Comment: The slip-on/fast-on or a bolt-on connectors I am asking about are in the link below.  These shown are for smaller gauge wires, but do they make them for larger gauge?

https://www.supplyhouse.com/DiversiTech-4214-High-Temperature-Female-Slip-On-Solderless-Terminal-16-14-AWG-Tab-Size-25-21-Pack?utm_source=google_ad&utm_medium=shopping_neutral&utm_campaign=Shopping_Neutral_New_users&gclid=CjwKCAjw8symBhAqEiwAaTA__FgJN6riedVaHriLjiXJPbpgRXa3dhu_schLe1MZWnQazTRlO7PWHhoCjwkQAvD_BwE

Comment: I also found this breaker and while it is larger in size the slots to connect it to the bus bar line up.  I know just because it fits does not mean it is to NEC, so if it did fit may not pass inspection.

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Siemens-200-Amp-Double-Pole-Type-QN-22kA-Circuit-Breaker-QN2200H/202276303

Comment: I don't see my neighbors wanting to split the cost of a new stack.  The neighbor above is very frugal, and both above and below would not see the benefit of upgrading their meter stack.  My neighbor above is looking to get an electric car, but he said he drives so little he'll just trickle charge his car through a 110 outlet in his garage.

Comment: My neighbor below has no garage so has no benefit to upgrade.  And I if were willing, I don't know if I could get away with just one stack since the stacks &terminal box are all adjacent.  I definitely would not be able to get 5 neighbors to upgrade.  all but mine and the neighbor below have simple access to the service line coming into their panel since it is on my garage wall & easily accessible through the garage ceiling.  With the lines secured to studs & no conduit, there is no easy way to change out the other lines for the neighbor above or across the stairwell without opening up walls.

Comment: I have read on other forums that meter boxes do have a lifespan 20-25 years and changing out old meter boxes are beneficial even without an upgrade.  These stacks are 36 years old.  But I don't see my neighbors buying into that even if the access to change out their service lines was not complicated.

Comment: @LukeCatania -- the reason why Dominion is using a 200A meter is because that's their standard as the meter doesn't set the ampacity of the service.  However, the sockets and such *do*.  If you could find another tapbox for your metering equipment, you *might* be able to use it along with a meter-main to pull 200A out, with your existing position "blanked off", but that'd require NOS hardware most likely, *and* explicit approval from your utility as well